# What does the "/" mean in this line from a Batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, find

I found this line of code in a post on here. I used it for my batch file, and it works. I'm just trying to understand what the '/' in the double quotes after the FIND command means.

```
    dir /a-d "\\SERVERNAME\SHARE\FOLDER\*.ext" | find /C "/"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's what it needs to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells the `find` command what string to find in the `dir` command which is being redirected to `find`. The `/c` tells `find` to output the count-of-lines-where-the target-string-is-found and hence if your date-separator is `/` then the count-of-files-found.

Comment: Thank you. I am pretty sure that it was intended to find the date-separator. What was throwing me off is if I put another variable in there, like an 'A', I get a count one higher than what I get with the '/'. (The files have very long names with most letters being represented in them.)

Answer (score 0):

If you enter

```
FIND /?
```

in a CMD window, `FIND` will tell you about its usage like that:

```
FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] [/OFF[LINE]] "string" [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

  /V         Displays all lines NOT containing the specified string.
  /C         Displays only the count of lines containing the string.
  /N         Displays line numbers with the displayed lines.
  /I         Ignores the case of characters when searching for the string.
  /OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
  "string"   Specifies the text string to find.
  [drive:][path]filename
             Specifies a file or files to search.

If a path is not specified, FIND searches the text typed at the prompt
or piped from another command.
```

So the string in double quotes it what you want `FIND` to find.

The `/?` option is supported and useful for a lot of the built-in DOS commands.

Answer (score 0):

The command line might be intended to get the count of matching files. Since `dir` returns a header, a list of files containing dates/times and sizes and a footer, the `/` might have been chosen as the search character, because this may only occur in the dates of the file list but not in the extra lines (header/footer). Here is an example output of `dir /A-D "\\SERVERNAME\SHARE\FOLDER\*.ext"`:

> ```
>  Volume in drive \\SERVERNAME\SHARE is DATA
>  Volume Serial Number is 0000-0000
>
>  Directory of \\SERVERNAME\SHARE\FOLDER
>
> 03/11/2016  12:00                 10 file.ext
> 03/11/2016  11:00                 26 sample.ext
>                2 File(s)             36 bytes
>                0 Dir(s)  99,999,999,964 bytes free
> ```

As you can see, the slash character (`/`) is only present in the dates, in case it is defined as date separator on the current machine, which makes the whole approach dependent on locale settings.

The pipe `|` transports this output to the next command, namely `find /C "/"`, which counts the number of lines (`/C`) that contain at least one `/` character.

---

If I am right with my suspicion, you could use the following line instead:

```
dir /B /A-D "\\SERVERNAME\SHARE\FOLDER\*.ext" | find /C /V ""
```

The `/B` switch tells `dir` to return a bare file list without any extras, like this, for instance:

> ```
> sample.ext
> file.ext
> ```

Then the `find /C /V ""` command counts (`/C`) all lines that do not match (`/V`) an empty string (`""`), hence it returns the total count of `*.ext` files in the given location. Opposed to the original approach, this one is totally independent from the locale and region settings.